# Which FireWire cable do I need to connect an iMac (late 2009) to a Thunderbolt to FireWire connection to retrieve the data using Diskmode?

Tags: imac, thunderbolt, target-disk-mode

I have an iMac (late 2009) with a broken graphics card. Fortunately, I have a new iMac (2019) which works fine.

I want to boot the old machine to Target Disk Mode to retrieve the data on the computer. I've read online you can connect them using a FireWire cable. Now the new mac doesn't have an FireWire connection but I think I can use a Thunderbolt to FireWire cable. So I thought I'll just order an FireWire cable, but there are a lot of different types. So my question is:

Which FireWire cable do I need to connect an iMac (late 2009) to a Thunderbolt to FireWire connection to retrieve the data using Target Disk Mode?

Comment: Isn't the choice limited by the type of connectors/ports on both ends anyway?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any single adapter/cable to directly connect Firewire 800 to Thunderbolt 3 (USBC form-factor.) The [OWC Thunderbolt 3 dock](https://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/TB3DK14PSG/) can do it, but at a pretty hefty price.

Comment: You're correct My error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iMac 2009 has a FireWire 800 port and the new iMac 2019 a Thunderbolt 3 port.

This requires three cables daisy-chained:

1. FireWire 800 - FireWire 800
2. FireWire 800 - Thunderbolt 1/2: [Apple Thunderbolt-naar-FireWire-adapter](https://www.apple.com/nl/shop/product/MD464ZM/A/apple-thunderbolt-naar-firewire-adapter)
3. Thunderbolt 1/2 - Thunderbolt 3: [Adapter voor Thunderbolt 3 (USB‑C) naar Thunderbolt 2](https://www.apple.com/nl/shop/product/MMEL2ZM/A/adapter-voor-thunderbolt-3-usb%E2%80%91c-naar-thunderbolt-2)

I found one source stating it's working: [Le Target Disk Mode marche en USB-C, en Thunderbolt et en FireWire](https://www.journaldulapin.com/2017/07/05/target-disk-mode/) (en français, with pics) and another one stating more or less the opposite: [Target mode between Macbook pro 2017 and Mac Pro 1.1](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8321702).

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for!